# pruning subdomains of other domains in a file using script (bash, awk or similar)

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, awk, grep

I have a huge size file (ten thousand entries) comprising of domains (in random order, but no duplicate domains and with an arbitrary number of subdomains), here is a little example:

```
domain.com
domain.net
sub.domain.com
anotherdomain.com
a.b.c.d.e.domain.net
5.4.3.2.1.domain.org
4.3.2.1.domain.org
```

EDIT: a proper working set is available at http://p.ip.fi/WRD- (the web page is slow, instant download with wget p.ip.fi/WRD- ).

I want to "prune" all the subdomains, i.e. write a new file removing all the subdomains of any other domains. In that example, it should end up like this (don't care about the sorting):

```
domain.com
domain.net
anotherdomain.com
4.3.2.1.domain.org
```

`sub.domain.com`, `a.b.c.d.e.domain.net` and `5.4.3.2.1.domain.org` are removed (being subdomains of `domain.com`, `domain.net` and `4.3.2.1.domain.org`), `anotherdomain.com` is kept, since it's just a different domain.

I tried different approaches with some optimizations, they worked, but they are too slow (many hours) because the file has ten thousand entries. To be useful it must be fast (max 1 minute or so). Here is what I have now:

```
> $TEMP_BLACKLIST
BL=`cat $BLACKLIST`
for ZONE1 in $BL; do
        KEEP=1
        # sed -e "1,/^$ZONE1$/d" -> optimization: print $BLACKLIST only *after* the $ZONE1 occourence
        # break                  -> optimization: quit the loop if not present
        for ZONE2 in `echo $BL | sed -e "1,/^$ZONE1$/d"`; do
                if [[ $ZONE1 == *.$ZONE2 ]] ; then
                        KEEP=0
                        break
                fi
        done
        if [ $KEEP = 1 ] ; then
                echo $ZONE1 >> $TEMP_BLACKLIST
        fi
done
mv $TEMP_BLACKLIST $BLACKLIST
```

The code should be contained inside a bash script, so just bash, eventually calling some common embedded script language (awk, Perl, or something) called from it (no custom C code).

Do you know any better approach?

Comment: Side note, I recommend you look into dnsmasq; you’ll like it.

Comment: @Wildcard thanks, indeed I am using this as a dangerous domains filtering system. I am using BIND in my university, and set up a script which download dangerous domains from some public lists and generate BIND zones redirecting to an internal web page telling the users the site is dangerous. It works fine for our 20.000+ users :). This script is for reducing zones BIND has to load (subdomains are already blocked anyway in the zone file). Not sure if dnsmasq is right for me, we have a complex network and I am using BIND since 10+ years.

Comment: dnsmasq should be faster as it won’t have to do a linear scan over 10000 lines for EACH name resolution.  And I’ve been very impressed with the cleverness and cleanliness of dnsmasq config options.  It’s a very well thought out tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another version

```
sed 's/^/\./' file |
    rev |
    LC_ALL=C sort -u |
    awk 'p == "" || substr($0,1,length(p)) != p { print $0; p = $0 }' |
    rev |
    sed 's/^\.//'
```

Input

```
domain.com
domain.net
sub.domain.com
anotherdomain.com
a.b.c.d.e.domain.net
5.4.3.2.1.domain.org
4.3.2.1.domain.org
b.c
a-b.c
b.b.c
btcapp.api.btc.com
btc.com
```

Output

```
a-b.c
b.c
4.3.2.1.domain.org
btc.com
domain.com
anotherdomain.com
domain.net
```

Trying with your recommended data set at http://p.ip.fi/WRD-, the source file I've collected contains 59683 lines and the filtered list has 34824. I see 36 lines with `grep btc.com | wc -l` applied to the filtered list.

Comment: Yes, your answer, now gives me the exact same result 34824. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```bsh
rev file \
| sort -u \
| tr '.' ',' \
| awk '$0!~dom_regex{print;dom_regex="^"$0"[.]";};NR==1{dom_regex="^"$0"[.]";print};' \
| tr ',' '.' \
| rev
```

Output:

```
4.3.2.1.domain.org
domain.com
anotherdomain.com
domain.net
```

Explanation:

1. `sort` the reversed file and eliminate duplicate lines. This step will group the  domains/subdomains of "one kind" together with the shortest one in front.
2. the `awk` part will look if the next one is of the same kind (saved as regex in variable `dom_regex`). If not, it will print the line and set new `dom_regex`. Otherwise, the line is skipped.
3. reverse the file again.

Comment: That wouldn't work properly if the input had `b.c` and `a.bxc` for instance. You should use `LC_ALL=C sort -u` and using something like `awk 'NR == 1 || index($0, prev ".") != 1 {print; prev = $0};'` instead of relying on regexps.

Comment: I fixed the issue by replacing `.`  with `,` ... , knowing that it's a fast workaround and not the most beautiful fix...

Comment: @Fabio, true, there's also a problem with `b.c`, `a-b.c`, `b.b.c` since `-` sorts before `.`

Comment: ah yeah... right ... I see, we need a proper solution ...

Comment: Doing a `LC_ALL=C sort -ut. -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4 -k5,5...` would address those I believe. Or `tr '.\1' '\1.' | LC_ALL=C sort -u | tr '.\1' '\1.'`

Comment: With rev $BLACKLIST | tr '.\1' '\1.' | LC_ALL=C sort -u | tr '.\1' '\1.' | awk 'NR == 1 || index($0, prev ".") != 1 {print; prev = $0};' | rev | sort I get 34824 lines, which appear to be just rigth! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you have only one domain extension.

```
awk -F '.' '!seen[$(NF-1)"."$NF]++' file

domain.com
domain.net
anotherdomain.com
```