Remove subdomains or existing domains
I have a list of domains, a sample is:
account.google.com
drive.google.com
google.com
bgoogle.com
yahoo.co.uk
stats.wikipedia.org
media.wikipedia.org
files.media.wikipedia.org
bible.com

I would like to remove all subdomains of existing domains. For example for the list above, because google.com and media.wikipedia.org have subdomains, those subdomains should be removed.
So the list above should result in:
google.com
bgoogle.com
yahoo.co.uk
stats.wikipedia.org
media.wikipedia.org
bible.com

I tried writing some code in python, but it will take a very long time to finish. How can I execute this task in the fastest way?

Why are stats.wikipedia.org and media.wikipedia.org kept and not collapsed into wikipedia.org?

If your input can contain ccTLDs such as yahoo.co.uk and google.co.uk then please include some of those in your sample input/output.

@EdMorton Ah, your edit makes it clearer. Hopefully that's even what they might have meant.

I still don't fully see the rule requirements here. (1) A domain to be kept should be considered at any level - not just single dot domains. (2) If there's a domain and its subdomains, discard the subdomains (accounts for both the google.com and the wikipedia.org sets). But why isn't bgoogle.com or bible.com processed in any way? Or is it that they can't be stripped back because ".com" is "too high" a level? And what should happen with country domains like UK - both {whatever}.co.uk and {whatever}.uk can be valid here (for the same {whatever}, even).

@Chris it's not that .com is too a high a level, it's that com doesn't exist in the file. A ccTLD would only be an issue if it also existed on it's own in the input file.

Ah! Light dawns. Thank you @EdMorton

I found the proper answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538859/579551

It sounds like your problem can be reformulated as "only keep the longest non-. followed by a . and the no other . until the end of the line; make these unique". If so, you can do something like:
$ awk -F"." -v OFS="." '{print $(NF-1),$(NF)}' file | sort -u
bgoogle.com
bible.com
google.com
wikipedia.org

Or, do the whole thing in awk:
$ awk -F"." '{ k[$(NF-1)"."$(NF)]++}END{for (i in k){print i}}' file 
bgoogle.com
bible.com
wikipedia.org
google.com


Or GNU grep:
$ grep -oP '[^.]+\.[^.]+$' file  | sort -u
bgoogle.com
bible.com
google.com
wikipedia.org

Or perl and GNU sort
$ perl -pe 's/.*?([^.]+\.[^.]+$)/$1/' file | sort -u
bgoogle.com
bible.com
google.com
wikipedia.org

Or just perl
$ perl -ne '$k{$1}++ for s/.*?([^.]+\.[^.]+$)/$1/; END{ print keys(%k) }' file 
bible.com
bgoogle.com
wikipedia.org
google.com

Or just perl
$ perl -ne 's/.*?([^.]+\.[^.]+)$/$1/; next if ++$k{$1}>1; print' file 
google.com
bgoogle.com
wikipedia.org
bible.com

Or sed and sort
$ sed -E 's/.*\.([^.]+\.[^.]+)$/\1/' file | sort -u
bgoogle.com
bible.com
google.com
wikipedia.org


$ sed -e 's/\./\\./g' -e 's,.*,/\\.&$/d,' file | sed -f /dev/stdin file
google.com
bgoogle.com
yahoo.co.uk
stats.wikipedia.org
media.wikipedia.org
bible.com

This first uses sed to create a sed editing script from the input file.  The sed command first escapes each dot on the current line, then turns the modified line into a d command with a particular regular expression trigger.
With the file presented in the question, this editing script would look like the following:
/\.account\.google\.com$/d
/\.drive\.google\.com$/d
/\.google\.com$/d
/\.bgoogle\.com$/d
/\.yahoo\.co\.uk$/d
/\.stats\.wikipedia\.org$/d
/\.media\.wikipedia\.org$/d
/\.files\.media\.wikipedia\.org$/d
/\.bible\.com$/d

This script will delete any input line containing a hostname ending with . followed by any of the hostnames in the original data.  This would, for example, delete aaa.bbb.ccc if bbb.ccc was in the data, because aaa.bbb.ccc would match the regular expression \.bbb\.ccc$.
The script is then applied to the original data with a second sed invocation, reading the editing script via its standard input stream.

With some small modifications to the initial sed command, we may do the elimination with grep in place of sed:
$ sed -e 's/\./\\./g' -e 's/.*/\\.&$/' file | grep -v -f /dev/stdin file
google.com
bgoogle.com
yahoo.co.uk
stats.wikipedia.org
media.wikipedia.org
bible.com

This creates a set of bare regular expressions for grep to read with -f:
\.account\.google\.com$
\.drive\.google\.com$
\.google\.com$
\.bgoogle\.com$
\.yahoo\.co\.uk$
\.stats\.wikipedia\.org$
\.media\.wikipedia\.org$
\.files\.media\.wikipedia\.org$
\.bible\.com$

The grep utility is used with -v which removes any matching lines from the input.

Nice approach, I wouldn't have thought of doing that (obviously, since I didn't!). Took me a few minutes to convince myself it was robust but it is.

Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)
...translating @terdon's excellent Perl solutions:
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my %k; %k{$0}++ for s/ .*? (<-[.]>+ \. <-[.]>+ $)/$0/; END .key.put for %k;'  file

#OR:

~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my %k; s/ .*? (<-[.]>+ \. <-[.]>+ $) /$0/; next if ++%k{$0} > 1; .put;'  file

Here are solutions coded in Raku, a member of the Perl family of programming languages. Raku features invariant "sigils" as well as a host of nice defaults, such as the ability to spread out regexes (/x-option in Perl). Custom character classes become <+[…]> for positive character classes and <-[…]> for negative character classes. Captures in Raku start from $0 unlike Perl which starts from $1.
Sample Input:
account.google.com
drive.google.com
google.com
bgoogle.com
stats.wikipedia.org
media.wikipedia.org
files.media.wikipedia.org
bible.com

Sample Output:
google.com
bgoogle.com
wikipedia.org
bible.com

https://raku.org

This might be what you're trying to do, using any awk:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    { doms[$0] }
    END {
        for ( dom in doms ) {
            n = gsub(/[.]/,"&",dom)
            parent = dom
            foundParent = 0
            for ( i=1; i<n; i++ ) {
                sub(/[^.]+\./,"",parent)
                if ( parent in doms ) {
                    foundParent = 1
                    break
                }
            }
            if ( !foundParent ) {
                print dom
            }
        }
    }
' "${@:--}"


$ ./tst.sh file
media.wikipedia.org
bgoogle.com
bible.com
google.com
stats.wikipedia.org

or, if you prefer to not store the whole file in memory in awk:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="." }
    {
        for ( i=NF; i>=1; i-- ) {
            printf "%s%s", $i, (i>1 ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
' "${@:--}" |
sort -u |
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="." }
    index($0,base".") != 1 {
        base = $0
        for ( i=NF; i>=1; i-- ) {
            printf "%s%s", $i, (i>1 ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }

'


$ ./tst.sh file
bgoogle.com
bible.com
google.com
media.wikipedia.org
stats.wikipedia.org

The first script above reads all of the domains into memory in the doms[] array and then loops through them stripping leading strings between "."s down to where there's only 2 left (so files.media.wikipedia.org becomes media.wikipedia.org and then fwikipedia.org), checking as we go if that parent string also exists in the doms[] array and, if it does then we know the current domain is a subdomain of that parent that was also present in the input and so we do not print it.
The second script uses awk to print each domain name in reverse, so files.media.wikipedia.org is printed as org.wikipedia.media.files and then the whole list is piped to sort -u which will discard duplicates (optional) and the result is that the shorter (i.e. parent) domain names will be printed immediately before their children subdomains. Then the subsequent awk just checks if the current reversed domain name is a substring at the start of the previous domain name that itself was not a subdomain - if so then this domain is a subdomain so skip it, if not then print it (re-reversing it back to it's original order) and remember this as the new base parent for the next domain to be compared to. Run each command separately to see what they output if that's not clear.
